# how to create two binaries file with same md5

Tags: c, cryptography, md5, md5sum

In seedlab, I am trying to create two binaries in a simple way. I can do it by the following:

In my C file, I have two arrays with 200 'A's

```
unsigned char a[200] = {0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41};
unsigned char b[200] ={0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41,0x41};

int main()
{
    int i;
    int flag = 1;

    for(i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        if(a[i] != b[I])
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
        if(flag)
        {
            printf("good");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("bad");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then I output by running

```
gcc sample.c -o sample.out
```

[Based on what this image states, I am able to cut the prefix and generate two files with same md5 but different 128-byte region(P or Q)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zICf4.png)

basically,using md5collgen to generate the 128-byte region:

```
md5collgen -p prefix -o out1.bin out2.bin
```

Now, I have two binary files with different p and q, but same md5.
Extract p and q, and using cat to do the following:

```
cat prefix p middle p end > prog1
cat prefix p middle q end > prog2
```

Middle and end are the part I extracted from sample.out file.
by running them, I got one prints out "good", and "bad" for the other one.
But the md5sum for prog1 and prog2 are the same.

My problem is this approach requires string comparison where p and q so that I can distinguish them by their different print outs.

Is there any other way to create two binary files but doesn't need memory or string comparison? I have a feeling it should not be hard but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Please [indent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) your code.

Comment: If you can determine which byte-pair in the arrays is the first one that is going to be different (in the "bad") case, then you could replace your for-loop with a single comparison of only that one byte-pair.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, Yes, I can determine which byte is the first one different. But I am looking for another way which doesn't use strings and string comparison at all.

Comment: Does comparing two bytes still count as a string comparison?  e.g. `int main(int, char**) {if (a[77]!=b[77]) printf("Bad\n"); else printf("Good\n");}`  (it might help if you explain *why* you want to avoid strings and string comparisons)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, this is basically what the Professor said. "To be more specifically, do not use array compare to bahave differently (functions such as memcmp, strcmp should not be used). Any other method is OK.". The way you did and for loop in my c code are similar to string comparison somehow, then there should not be used in my understanding.